# Unable to Search Table Containing Webform Submissions Using Exposed Combined Fields Filter

Tags: webforms, search, views, theming

I'm trying to add a Combined Fields Filter that users can come to my site and use to search through a Table View that is populated by user-created Webform submissions.  Unfortunately, when I create said filter, it never returns any results.

Below are the settings I have now:

View Settings
[image: View Settings]

Filter Settings
[image: Filter Settings]

Is this something you can do with webform submissions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all of the fields text fields?  That is... do each of them allow a 'contains' filter if filtered individually?

Comment: Hi Darvanen, unfortunately, no - if I create a Combined Fields Filter with one of the text fields and nothing else, the same phenomenon occurs.  No results when I search for anything.  Almost all of the fields in the webform are text fields, save 2 radio buttons and 2 checklists.

Comment: Hi Darvanen, update:  [Here's an image of a grouped filter I'm trying to use so people can filter by category](http://i.imgur.com/mNusUZW.png).  Does this look wrong?

Comment: Sounds to me like Combined Fields filter is buggy.  Try a normal filter on one of your text fields to see if that works?